# use sha for CSP in chrome app for inline <script> tag (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, content-security-policy

I meet a problem using angular in Chrome app because of CSP violation. I tried to add hash to inline  tag, but app dont recognise CSP manifest key

```
There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
*Unrecognized manifest key 'Content-Security-Policy'.
```

The part of the code, which making a problem is

```
<script>System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){  console.error(err); });</script>
```

Manifest.js

```
{
"name": "test-app",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Test.",
"manifest_version": 2,
"minimum_chrome_version": "40.0.2213.0",
"app": {
 "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
},
"permissions": ["usb"],
"icons": {
 "128": "icon_128.png"
},
"Content-Security-Policy": "script-src 'sha256qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0FCKCzCG+HiZ1guq6ZZDob/Tng='"
}
```

Te question is: how to use a SHA for a chrome app (CSP are forced in apps, but not in extensions)
Any idea how to make it work, or how to omit that script to make it work (its for angular boostraping)

I already read https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy

and https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150721/#script-src-hash-usage

but it was fruitless

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're missing a "-" dash, which goes in between the sha256 and your code.

e.g.
sha256-qznLcsROx4GACP2dm0FCKCzCG+HiZ1guq6ZZDob/Tng=

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use this `"content_security_policy"` instead of `"Content-Security-Policy"`

Comment: While this code change may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this change answers the question improves its long-term value.